# PHP: syntax error, unexpected 'else'

Tags: php, if-statement

I got a syntax error when trying to set an username in my header, handling the exception when no first name and last name is seated, using the username to fill the label, surely is a stupid error.
I'm using Quadodo Login Script in my project by the easily implementing.

Here is the code:

```
if(isset($qls->user_info['firstname'] { 
  $realname = "$qls->user_info['firstname'] . ' ' . $qls->user_info['lastname']"
} else { 
  $realname = "$qls->user_info['username']"
};
```

Comment: You have forget semicolon in your Both statement lines.

Comment: missed semi colons..

Comment: you are right @RaviHirani

Comment: And why do you have semicolons at the end of else?

Comment: Thanks guys for all your answers, as expected was a distraction error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forget semicolon as well as ending bracket in your code.

```
 // add two ending brackets in below line.
    if(isset($qls->user_info['firstname'])) { 
      // add semicolon in this line
      $realname = "$qls->user_info['firstname'] . ' ' . $qls->user_info['lastname']";
    } else { 
       // add semicolon in this line
      $realname = "$qls->user_info['username']";
    } //removed semicolon
```

Comment: You missed two closing braces for isset

Comment: @GaganUpadhyay: Thanks brother. I have edited my answer with comments.

Comment: Thanks, i'm feeling stupid! maybe i must to do a pause when coding a lot!

Comment: @Ravi - remove semicolon after else

Comment: @charlotte: Thanks for your edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($qls->user_info['firstname'])){ 
  $realname = "$qls->user_info['firstname'] . ' ' . $qls->user_info['lastname']";
} else { 
  $realname = "$qls->user_info['username']";
}
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Well this is because you realy messed up this code. Here is good version:

```
if(isset($qls->user_info['firstname'])) {
$realname = $qls->user_info['firstname'] . ' ' . $qls->user_info['lastname'];
} else {
$realname = $qls->user_info['username'];
};
```

I would suggest to use some IDE which will tell you when you have syntax error

Comment: I'm using C9IDE, but i'm coding for 5 hours whit out a pause! thanks